# Why Laravel only saves 1 image out of multiple images uploaded?

Tags: file-upload, laravel-8

I have a `<input type="file" id="uploadfiles" name="uploadfiles[]">` set my form `enctype='multipart/form-data'` and I don't know why I can only save the first image selected even I select multiple images. Here says I have selected 2 files:

[image]

But in the controller, it only saves the 1st image.

This is my controller

```
if ($request->hasFile('uploadfiles')) {
$cntr = 0;
    $images = $request->uploadfiles;
    foreach ($images as $key => $file) {

        $tstamp = '_' . now()->format('YmdHis'). $cntr ;

        $orgnlname = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $tempext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $tempfilename = pathinfo($orgnlname)['filename']. $tstamp. '.' . $tempext;

        if ($key==2) {
            return 123;
        }
        $img = Image::make($file)->encode($tempext, 50);

        Storage::disk('local')->put('/private/uploads/'.$modulename.'/'. $tempfilename, $img, 'private');

        $cntr++;
    }
}
```

It's been 3 days since I started to fix this issue. but I think now I need help.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the cause of foreach with $key attribute;

You can directly start with;

```
if ( isset($request->uploadfiles) ) {

            foreach(request()->file('uploadfiles') as $file){

//yourcodehere

        }
```